# Phoenix + React, is it possible to fetch data from other database table with Repo.preload?

Tags: reactjs, phoenix-framework

```
orders = Repo.all(from p in Order, where: p.created_date >= ^from, order_by: [desc: p.inserted_at])
  |> Repo.preload(:payment)
  |> Repo.preload(:staff)
```

In `phoenix-framework`, by using `Repo.preload`, I can fetch data from other database table. For above code, I can get `name`in `Staffs` database table with `<%= order.staff.name %>` in html file.

I am using `react` as front-end framework. And I am trying to do same thing that above code does.

I get data from database with same code as above. I expected that with `Repo.preload` it will provide other table's data. But `console.log(this.props)` does not show any data from other database table...   How can I do this with `react`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You can't access the database from your front end framework, you have to make requests over HTTP calls. How are you passing the `orders` to your front end application?

Comment: As an aside, you can preload two associations with a single preload call by using a list.

If you look at the docs for [Repo.preload/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3) then you will see you can do `Repo.preload([:payment, :staff])` to preload both.

Comment: I am getting data from `channel`, when a user joins to channel, it fetches data, passes it to action and then stores it to reducer as one of states..

Comment: Oh I see.... I should try other approaches... Now I am trying `join` to get data